# Adding UIPicker to textfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a table view & I have to display text fields in some cells. When user click on the text field, I want the picker view to be displayed with integer values from 0 to 99. once the user selects the item in picker view the same needs to be displayed on that particular text field. Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: can u show me what have u tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   -(void) viewDidLoad
 {
arrayNo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[arrayNo addObject:@"1"];
[arrayNo addObject:@"2"];
[arrayNo addObject:@"3"];
// and so on....
  }
```

Add target of this line to ur textfield function

```
  UITextfield *entered2;
  //..... some codes
   [entered2 addTarget:self action:@selector(showPicker)forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];
[myview addSubview:entered2];




  -(void) showPicker
  {
[entered2 resignFirstResponder];
    pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,240,220,0)];

pickerView.delegate = self;
pickerView.dataSource = self;
pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;    

[self.view addSubview:pickerView];  
[pickerView release]; 
 }

 - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component 
   {
    return [arrayNo count];
   }
  - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
 return 1;  
   }
   - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
   {
entered2.text=[arrayNo objectAtIndex:row];
[pickerView removeFromSuperview];
   }
    - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
   {
return [arrayNo objectAtIndex:row];
[pickerView removeFromSuperview];
   }
   - (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
int sectionWidth = 300;
return sectionWidth;
     }
```

Comment: Thanks, the code works fine, but there is a slight problem, when i click on the text field multiple times then the picker view does not dismiss on one selection, rather it will dismiss after selecting the input to that many times i have clicked text field.

Comment: And one more thing can we have a done button on a title to dismiss the picker view, when user selects the input.

Comment: Ok, thanks I managed to solve the both problems, thanks for the direction you give me :)

Comment: sorry. just nw i seen ur comment. dnt wry its simple add done button to the pickerview.

Answer (score 1):

Swift iOS: (Note: please change vars name by requirement)

Step 1 : declare vars and objects

```
var objPickerView  : UIPickerView = UIPickerView()

// select the picker view data values
objPickerView.delegate=self;
objPickerView.dataSource=self;
objPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator=true;

// show picker view when text field clicked   
self.smokingStatusText!.inputView = objPickerView


// reload the component of picker
self.objPickerView.reloadAllComponents()

// select the value of picker status(Which row must be selected)
self.objPickerView.selectRow(sStatus!, inComponent: PickerComponent.size.rawValue, animated: false)
```

Step 2: declare delegates and protocol:

```
// programming mark ----- ---- ----- ----- ---- ----- ----- ---- -----

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

// programming mark ----- ---- ----- ----- ---- ----- ----- ---- -----

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerData.count
}

//MARK: UIPickerView Delegates

// programming mark ----- ---- ----- ----- ---- ----- ----- ---- -----

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    smokingStatusText!.text = pickerData[row]
    self.smokerStatusNum = String(row)

}

// programming mark ----- ---- ----- ----- ---- ----- ----- ---- -----

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {

    let titleData = pickerData[row]

    let font:UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 14.0)

    let attrString = NSAttributedString(
        string: titleData,
        attributes: NSDictionary(
            object: font!,
            forKey: NSFontAttributeName))

    return attrString
}

// programming mark ----- ---- ----- ----- ---- ----- ----- ---- -----

//size the components of the UIPickerView
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 36.0
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 300
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a picker view and implement the delegate and datasource methods in your view controller. Set the picker view as the `inputview` of your text field. It will then pop up instead of the keyboard when the user edits the text field.

Use the `didSelect...` delegate methods to update the text field value when the user alters the picker.

Comment: In that case picker view comes at the position of keyboard, but instead I want at just below my text field

Comment: You mean the picker view should always be visible?

Comment: When i set picker view as input view of text field, my picker view comes at the position of key board, but instead I want my picker view, to be shown just behind my text field

Answer (score 0):

First in the viewDidLoad method you need to instantiate the PickerView and to add it to the textField

```
UIPickerView *pickerView =[[UIPickerView alloc]init];
pickerView.delegate=self;
pickerView.dataSource=self;
pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator=YES;
myTextField.inputView=pickerView;
```

Then you have to implement the UIPickerView delegate

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView 
      didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row 
       inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    myTextField.text=[arrayWithData objectAtIndex:row];
 }
```

Where arrayWithData is the array with the source for the PickerView.