# Adding a UI Picker to a UITextView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextview, uipickerview

I'm trying to add a `UIPicker` to a `UITextView` when it is selected to choose an age. I found a previous [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064367/adding-uipicker-to-textfield) and trued to implement the code but I can't get it to work properly. When I build the program the picker shows up, but there are no values in it. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? Also, I'm getting two yellow errors here saying "Assigning to 'id' from incompatible type 'ViewController *const __strong" here:

```
pickerView.delegate = self;
pickerView.dataSource = self;
```

Thank you.

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *ageTextField;

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize ageTextField;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIPickerView *pickerView =[[UIPickerView alloc]init];
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator=YES;
    ageTextField.inputView=pickerView;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)PickerView
      didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
       inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    NSMutableArray *ageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [ageArray addObject:@"1"];
    [ageArray addObject:@"2"];
    [ageArray addObject:@"3"];
    [ageArray addObject:@"4"];

    ageTextField.text=[ageArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@interface ViewController () <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPickerView *pickerView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *pickerElements;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    self.pickerView.delegate = self;
    self.pickerView.dataSource = self;
    self.pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    self.ageTextField.inputView = self.pickerView;

    self.pickerElements = @[@"text1", @"text2", @"text3", @"text4"];
    [self pickerView:self.pickerView
        didSelectRow:0
         inComponent:0];
}

- (int)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (int)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
     return [self.pickerElements count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [self.pickerElements objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    self.ageTextField.text = [self.pickerElements objectAtIndex:row];
}

@end
```

Comment: True. I was messing around with it and forgot to change it back. Thanks. I'll edit that.

Comment: are you implementing the method `pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:`?

Comment: No. Would that be this: ageTextField.text=[ageArray objectAtIndex:component]; ?

Comment: Oh one thing, will the picker dismiss once a value is chosen?

Comment: What exactly does that mean? Do I need to write more code to dismiss the picker after a value is chosen? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, after the selection is made you can `[pickerView removeFromSuperView];` Note that you will have to add the pickerView back to your view should you need it again. Other options would be to hide it or animate off the screen's frame using uiview animation code. Whichever suits your needs best.

Comment: when you say dismiss the `pickerView` are referring to hide it?, if so, all you has to do is call `[self.ageTextField resignFirstResponder]`, you are assigning the `pickerView` "as the keyboard" for your `ageTextField` field